# How to delete permanently uncategorized in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, api, vue.js, axios, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to permanently remove the uncategorized category in WordPress. I do not think it is possible. I am using wp api in my vue.js project. I am using Axios, is there a way to get all categories from the api but excluding the uncategorized category?

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a different category as the `Default Post Category` under WP `Settings > Writing`.

[image]

Only after that you can delete the `Uncategorized` category

[image]

EDIT:

Please note that my answer doesn't `transform` `uncategorized` category. But it gives you an option to completely delete it (Please see the screenshots. When you change the default post category, WP allows you to delete Uncategorized category). The thing is, Wordpress needs to have a `default category` in its settings. So you need to have at least one `default category` in place.

Comment: the thing is I do not want to transform the uncategorized category into another category. I need to permanently delete it, so it does not show up when I fetch all categories of the api. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: You can use the 'exclude' => 1 in your query where 1 is the id of your uncategorized category. Please see here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/187443/exclude-a-category-if-post-is-only-in-that-category-using-wp-query